# :after selector under content?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a problem. I'm trying to get a button to click right with CSS :after selector.

```
.text-bg .text-top-left{
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
    background:rgba(95,87,79,0.9);
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    top:50px;
    left:-48%;
}

.text-bg .text-top-left:after{
    content:'>';
    font-family:'Entypo';
    width:20px;
    height:10px;    
    color:black;
    background:white;
}
```

Right now the > is under my content in my text-top-left. But I need it to be on the right side, centered, outside of the box. What do I have to change?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w1v07drv/)

Tried: `position:absolute, float:right, text-align:right`

Comment: Your code is cool. But can you fiddle your code?

Comment: Try `position: absolute;`

Comment: A little bit of html would help to have the page structure

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/w1v07drv/2/)

Comment: Or this: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/w1v07drv/3/

Comment: @Benjamin , why does this top:0, bottom:0, margin:auto work? I mean normally margin only works on width, no?

Comment: @FrederikWitte if the elements is absolute the margin works with top and bottom when you have a specific height. It works according to your relative parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play around with `top,left,right,bottom` value in `:after` selector.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/w1v07drv/1/

CSS:

```
.text-bg .text-top-left {
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
    background:rgba(95, 87, 79, 0.9);
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    top:50px;
    left:0;
}
.text-bg .text-top-left:after {
    content:'>';
    font-family:'Entypo';
    width:20px;
    height:10px;
    color:#FFF;
    position:absolute; // Add this
    top:0; // to place it at the top
    right:10px; //to place it extreme right at the offset of 10px
}
```

**For Right**:
Change `right` to 0 or any preferred value.

**For Left** : Modify `left`

..and so on